# Regular expression to get decimal value from string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to trim value out of string and then divide it by some value but my regular expression returns me zero or one.

```
select (trim(total) regexp '^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$')/3 as total_c
from test;
```

how can I get actual value instead of 0 or 1.
e.g from `A9.9` i want `3.3` in the end.
Sample date for total column:

```
    A9.9
    ABC2.2
    2.3xyz
    22
    .....
```

Comment: Post some sample data,you might be able to do this without regex, which is slow.

Comment: Is the number always at the beginning or end o the string?

Comment: can be any where, but mostly in the end

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for regular expression replacing in Mysql.
You will have to use user defined functions like [**REGEX_REPLACE()**](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/) or you can use [**PREG_CAPTURE()**](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg)

As far as your query is concerned

```
select (trim(total) regexp '^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$')/3 as total_c
from test;
```

regular expression followed by `regexp` operator is not matched and returns value 0 and so you are getting 0 as result.